# How to compile boost async_client.cpp

Tags: boost

What is the correct command to compile this code?
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/http/client/async_client.cpp
I had installed boost library in /usr/include/boost

Comment: Please include any relevant code in the question instead of posting a link.

Answer (score 2):

E.g.

```
clang++ -std=c++03 -Wall -pedantic -g -O2 async_client.cpp -o async_client -lboost_system -lboost_thread -lpthread
```

Assuming your system's packaged version of Boost (or pre-configured include & lib paths). To make use of your custom built Boost library tree in `~/custom/boost`:

```
clang++ -std=c++03 -Wall -pedantic -g -O2 \
     -isystem ~/custom/boost/ ~/custom/boost/libs/asio/example/cpp03/http/client/ \
     async_client.cpp -o async_client \
     -L ~/custom/boost/stage/lib/ -Wl,-rpath,/home/sehe/custom/boost/stage/lib \
     -lboost_system -lboost_thread -lpthread
```

Replace `clang++` by `g++` at will.

`-std=c++03 -Wall -pedantic -g -O2` only for expositional purposes.