# Compile with boost to use whatever boost version is available?

Tags: c++, boost, compilation

I've compiled a Linux package on ubuntu 12.04 which uses boost and on this system i have boost 1.46. I tried to run the compiled release on another system and it complains that it can't find libboost_system.so.1.46.1.  That system has boost 1.49 installed.  How do I compile so that the program uses whatever version of boot exists instead of the specific version on the development machine.

Comment: One option might be statically linking against Boost instead of your current dynamic linking setup. I don't know whether all of the Boost libraries support this.

Comment: what compiler/linker options are you using?

Comment: Different `boost` versions have different binary interfaces.  Barring extreme hanky panky, you cannot do this.

Comment: statically linking the boost library, as Jason R suggests, is the correct way to handle this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot expect your program to work with a different version of the library.

The fact that there are /different/ versions implies that they're /not the same/.

As mentioned, either

- statically link to your specific version, or
- you can ship the shared libraries (as long as you put them in a app-specific location and make sure you find them at runtime). Incidentally, see the second example here: [How to compile boost async_client.cpp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22312653/how-to-compile-boost-async-client-cpp/22313790#22313790) for the relevant linker options to use a custom library (it assumes the same location is to be used at runtime (`rpath`)