# Running HTTP server example from Boost Asio

Tags: c++, linux, http, boost, boost-asio

I'm getting errors when trying to run the HTTP server example that comes with the source of the boost library, under the path: `boost_1_59_0/libs/asio/example/cpp11/http/server/`.

I already ran this following commands in the `boost_1_59_0` directory:

- `$ ./bootstrap.sh`
- `$ sudo ./bjam install`
- `$ sudo ./b2 install`

After installing all targets, i tried to compile the main.cpp and the server.cpp with this command: `g++ -std=c++0x -o main main.cpp -I "/home/user/Desktop/boost_1_59_0" -L "/home/user/Desktop/boost_1_59_0/libs/" -lboost_system`.
Any suggestion on how to compile this server example?

I linked all files from the `boost_1_59_0/libs/asio/example/cpp11/http/server/` folder after the main.cpp, as @Richard Hodges suggested. It still didn't work, i got errors concerning *lpthread*, so i added it to the compiling options. The program compiled but it failed the execution, returning an error saying that it didn't find the library *libboost_system.so.1.59.0*. I tried linking the folders with `-L /path/to/library` but it didn't work.

**Solution:**

My compilation command:

```
g++ -std=gnu++0x -o main main.cpp server.cpp connection.cpp connection_manager.cpp reply.cpp mime_types.cpp request_handler.cpp request_parser.cpp -I "/home/user/Desktop/boost_1_59_0" -lboost_system -lpthread
```

I solved it with this commands:

- `$ LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/local/lib/"`
- `$ sudo ldconfig`

And then I just ran the executable and it worked!

Comment: what command line did you use to compile the example? did you remember `-lboost-system`? what error output did you get?

Comment: I used this command: `g++ -std=c++0x -o main main.cpp -I "/home/user/Desktop/boost_1_59_0" -L "/home/user/Desktop/boost_1_59_0/libs/" -lboost_system`.

I had an error about `undefined reference to `http::server::server::run()`

Comment: you need to mention all the other .cpp files on the command line. they go just after main.cpp

Comment: Thanks for the help Richard!

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22314951/compile-with-boost-to-use-whatever-boost-version-is-available/22318955?s=1|0.7265#22318955

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a simple makefile I just concocted that works:

```
all:server

CPPFLAGS+=-std=c++11 -Wall -pedantic
CPPFLAGS+=-g -O2

CPPFLAGS+=-pthread
LDFLAGS+=-lboost_system

%.o:%.cpp
    $(CXX) $(CPPFLAGS) $^ -c -o $@

server:$(patsubst %.cpp,%.o,$(wildcard *.cpp))
    $(CXX) $(CPPFLAGS) $^ -o $@ $(LDFLAGS)
```

It runs `make`:

```
g++ -std=c++11 -Wall -pedantic -g -O2 -pthread connection.cpp -c -o connection.o
g++ -std=c++11 -Wall -pedantic -g -O2 -pthread connection_manager.cpp -c -o connection_manager.o
g++ -std=c++11 -Wall -pedantic -g -O2 -pthread main.cpp -c -o main.o
g++ -std=c++11 -Wall -pedantic -g -O2 -pthread mime_types.cpp -c -o mime_types.o
g++ -std=c++11 -Wall -pedantic -g -O2 -pthread reply.cpp -c -o reply.o
g++ -std=c++11 -Wall -pedantic -g -O2 -pthread request_handler.cpp -c -o request_handler.o
g++ -std=c++11 -Wall -pedantic -g -O2 -pthread request_parser.cpp -c -o request_parser.o
g++ -std=c++11 -Wall -pedantic -g -O2 -pthread server.cpp -c -o server.o
g++ -std=c++11 -Wall -pedantic -g -O2 -pthread connection.o connection_manager.o main.o mime_types.o reply.o request_handler.o request_parser.o server.o -o server -lboost_system
```

And the test program runs:

```
$ ./server 0.0.0.0 9889 . & 
$ GET http://localhost:9889/main.cpp > main.cpp.0
```

Check the files

```
$ md5sum main.cpp*
be5dc1c26b5942101a7895de6baedcee  main.cpp
be5dc1c26b5942101a7895de6baedcee  main.cpp.0
```

Don't forget to kill the server when you're done